# How to implement search autocomplete for specific content types?

Tags: 8

How to implement [search autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) it should show suggestions for specific content type only suppose recipe and collection .

I have used **search exclude(node)** module for searching nodes of specific content types.

But i am not able to figure out how to add search autocomplete programatically  or by using some module.

Comment: yes but its giving suggestion of all content type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new view of content. Click on <kbd>+ Add</kbd>  select `Autocompletion Callback` and add a path/url to it.

In Filter add Type filter so only shows certain content types.

In `/admin/config/search/search_autocomplete` edit the search block

For **WHAT - WHAT TO DISPLAY IN SEARCH AUTOCOMPLETE SUGGESTIONS?** change this to your view's autocompletion callback.

For more info read the [documentation](https://drupal-addict.com/nos-projets/search-autocomplete#User_documentation).